# Using HRFORM and HRFORMS_METADATA

Tags: forms, abap

I am changing a FORM using the transaction HRFORMS and HRFORMS_METADATA, I did create a new field

```
MetaDimensions->ZBAN_SWIFT2

Using MF -> ZHRCA_READ_BANK_2 that have
Interface local:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(BANK_COUNTRY) LIKE  BNKA_BF-BANKS
*"     REFERENCE(BANK_NUMBER) LIKE  BNKA_BF-BANKL
*"     REFERENCE(SPRSL) TYPE  SPRAS DEFAULT SY-LANGU
*"  EXPORTING
*"     VALUE(SWIFT) TYPE  SWIFT

  data
      it_bank TYPE bnka-SWIFT.

SELECT swift
  FROM bnka
  INTO it_bank
       WHERE  banks  = bank_country
       AND    bankl  = bank_number.

ENDSELECT.

SWIFT = it_bank.

MetaFields

   Key        MetaFields         type Field 
    X       BANK_COUNTRY           BANKS
    X       BANK_NUMBER            BANKK
Attribute
    X          SWIFT               SWIFT


Create MetaStar

ZDADOS_SWIFT

where:

MetaDimension        MetaFields         type Field 
  ZBAN_SWIFT2       BANK_COUNTRY           BANKS
  ZBAN_SWIFT2       BANK_NUMBER            BANKK
```

then I save and on transaction HRFORMS I pass the new fields to INFONET then activate...
But the program print that is generated automatically, it changes the call to my function module, generating `EXPORTING` instead of `CHANGING`.

```
METHOD read_ZBAN_SWIFT2.
  define_dim_fs ZBAN_SWIFT2.

  LOOP AT formdata-dim_ZBAN_SWIFT2
          ASSIGNING <dwa_ZBAN_SWIFT2> WHERE
            SWIFT IS INITIAL AND
            ( NOT key IS INITIAL or key IS INITIAL ).

* Call the function which fills the dimension attributes
    CALL FUNCTION 'ZHRCA_READ_BANK_2'
      EXPORTING
        sprsl         = language
        BANK_COUNTRY  = <dwa_ZBAN_SWIFT2>-key-BANK_COUNTRY
        BANK_NUMBER   = <dwa_ZBAN_SWIFT2>-key-BANK_NUMBER
      CHANGING
        SWIFT         = <dwa_ZBAN_SWIFT2>-SWIFT
      EXCEPTIONS
        display_error = 4
        no_authority  = 3
        others        = 0.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      CALL METHOD insert_message( ).
    ENDIF.

  ENDLOOP.
ENDMETHOD.          "read_ZBAN_SWIFT2
```

at the end this is the error

An exception occurred that is explained in detail below.
 The exception, which is assigned to class `CX_SY_DYN_CALL_PARAM_NOT_FOUND`, was
  not caught in
 procedure `READ_ZBAN_SWIFT2 (METHOD)`, nor was it propagated by a RAISING
  clause.
 Since the caller of the procedure could not have anticipated that the
 exception would occur, the current program is terminated.
 The reason for the exception is:
 Function module `ZHRCA_READ_BANK_2` was called
 with the parameter `SWIFT`.
 This parameter is not defined.

Can any one tell my why?

Comment: Are you sure it is transaction `HRFORM` and not `HRFORMS`???

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer. If this helped you, then upvoting and accepting it would be highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example delivered in SAP standard. It is function module `HRF_READ_BANK_ATTRIBUTES`. If you have a look at it you will see that all the output parameters are defined as `CHANGING`.

I guess this framework expects the output parameters to be defined exactly like that.

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(SPRSL) TYPE  SPRAS DEFAULT SY-LANGU
*"     REFERENCE(BEGDA) TYPE  BEGDA DEFAULT '18000101'
*"     REFERENCE(ENDDA) TYPE  ENDDA DEFAULT '99991231'
*"     REFERENCE(BANK_NUMBER) TYPE  BANKL
*"     REFERENCE(CONTROL_KEY) TYPE  BKONT
*"     REFERENCE(COUNTRY) TYPE  LAND1
*"  CHANGING
*"     REFERENCE(BANK_NAME) TYPE  BANKA OPTIONAL
*"     REFERENCE(ADDRESS_KEY) TYPE  ADRNR OPTIONAL
*"     REFERENCE(BANK_BRANCH) TYPE  BRNCH OPTIONAL
*"  EXCEPTIONS
*"      DISPLAY_ERROR
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
```